# How to prevent mouse cursor from disappearing when Space key down in QT application on Mac 13

Tags: qt

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int c = 0;
    QApplication app(c, nullptr);
    QMainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Mouse cursor disappears when I press Space Key down while this application running on MacOS.
It also disappears when other alphabet or number key down.
How to prevent this?

I'm using QT 6.3.1 on MacOS 13.3

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Originally, in the current situation, pressing the space bar, letter keys and number keys not only triggers a KeyPressEvent, but also simultaneously triggers an InputMethodQueryEvent, which is the reason why the mouse cursor disappears.
Therefore, intercepting the InputMethodQuery event can prevent the mouse cursor from disappearing.